# Merging two rows in R while appending a specific column of the first row with a string from the second row

Tags: r, string, data-wrangling

I'm trying to tidy some archived OCR-files. One step includes to detect subheaders in the document. As some subheaders have a length of 2 lines, they are separated from the beginning of the respective header.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(header = c("1. hello", "2. halo", "hallow"), line_id = c(28:30))
```

I want to delete the row without the digit at the beginning but paste the content of the header column after the content of the row above.

Expected result:

```
df_clean <- data.frame(header = c("1. hello", "2. halo hallow"), line_id = c(28,29))
```

Comment: And you just want to throw away the value of 30? Will there ever be more than one row that needs to be combined?

Comment: Yes, I need the subheaders only as metadata. All together there are around 20 subheaders that are longer than one line per document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be to "group" by rows where the `header` begins with a number, and then combine those rows with `paste`. This would allow for multiple rows to be combined.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(grepl("^\\d+.", header))) %>%
  summarise(header = paste(header, collapse = " "), line_id = first(line_id))
```

**Output**

```
    grp header         line_id
  <int> <chr>            <int>
1     1 1. hello            28
2     2 2. halo hallow      29
```